# I had to rename my files and now my runner will not function

Tags: java

I had to rename two files, and now they won't work when I run the demo file. I am a beginner to programming and cannot identify why my methods will not properly connect to the other file containing its constructors, methods, etc. Can someone please help me identify what is going wrong? Specifically, `myCube.calcCubeArea(side)` is not working, and I don't know why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class keelanbaxter_185A01_Cubedemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the type of units: ");
        String units = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of sides: ");
        double side = sc.nextInt();

        keelanbaxter_185A01_Cubedemo myCube1 = new keelanbaxter_185A01_Cubedemo();
        myCube1.setSide(side);

        System.out.println("The units you have chosen are: " + units + " and the side length is: " + side + units);

        System.out.println("The area of the cube is: " + myCube1.calcCubeArea(side));
        System.out.println("The volume of the cube is: " + myCube1.calcCubeVolume(side));

    }
}
```

```
public class keelanbaxter_185A01_Cube {
    private double side;
    private static String units;

    public void setSide(double S) {
        side = S;
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setUnits(String uni) {
        units = uni;
    }

    public String getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public double calcCubeVolume(double volume) {
        return volume = side*side*side;
    }

    public double calcCubeArea(double area) {
        return area = side*side;
    }
}
```

Comment: The names of the files need to match the class names. What did you call them? Also, you should follow the Java naming conventions. https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions It will make it easier for others to help you. And finally, the names of your classes are super complicated. Why? You should simplify them.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are not calling the correct class name, change this part:

```
    keelanbaxter_185A01_Cube myCube1 = new keelanbaxter_185A01_Cube();
    myCube1.setSide(side);
```

Comment: Hi, Angela. This was the solution. I am not sure how I missed this, but like I said I am new to programming. Thank you for pointing this out and clarifying.